# Changing Port on HUG

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services, hug

Is it possible to change the port number on HUG for python?
I have the following sample of what I'm trying to do.
The API defaults to port 8000 but I want to be able to set it manually.

```
@hug.post()
def receive_json(request):
    request=str(request)
    print("Hello! Glad you're here!")
    print(request)
    process=os.system("echo "+'"'+request+'"')
```

Answer (score 6):

add at the end of your `app.py` (or whatever it's name is) file:

```
hug.API(__name__).http.serve(port=8005)
```

for serving on port **8005**

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `hug` command line script to start your app, the `-p / --port` option will get you there, as in `hug --port 5000 -f app.py`:

```
$ hug --help
usage: hug [-h] [-v] [-f FILE] [-m MODULE] [-p PORT] [-n] [-ma] [-i INTERVAL]
           [-c COMMAND]

Hug API Development Server

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --version         show program's version number and exit
  -f FILE, --file FILE  file
  -m MODULE, --module MODULE
                        module
  -p PORT, --port PORT  A Whole number
  -n, --no_404_documentation
                        Providing any value will set this to true
  -ma, --manual_reload  Providing any value will set this to true
  -i INTERVAL, --interval INTERVAL
                        A Whole number
  -c COMMAND, --command COMMAND
                        command
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Gunicorn to serve the hug app and use the -b flag to bind to a different port.

`gunicorn --reload myapp:__hug_wsgi__ -b0.0.0.0:8008`